# Unable to acquire the state change lock for the module: osgi.identity on Windows server 2012

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-server-2012-r2

I am not able to open eclipse downloaded on a remote desktop running on Windows server 2012 R2 standard edition. How do I solve this issue?
Here is what I have tried:

- Deleted configuration/.log file
- Deleted .fileTable.1, .fileTable.2, .fileTableLock in configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager
- Deleted framework.info.1 in configuration/org.eclipse.osgi

I am not at liberty to restart the shared server.
This is in my .eclipseproduct:

```
name=Eclipse Platform
id=org.eclipse.platform
version=4.6.3
```

And here is the beginning of the log file:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2018-02-16 10:28:57.812
!MESSAGE [SCR] Enabling components of bundle org.eclipse.ui.trace did not complete in 30000 ms

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2018-02-16 10:29:02.855
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to acquire the state change lock for the module: osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.runtime"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.12.0.v20160606-1342"; singleton:="true" [id=98] STARTED [STARTED]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after waiting 5 seconds to acquire the lock.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:334)
    ... 8 more
Root exception:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after waiting 5 seconds to acquire the lock.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this issue is old, but still wanted to add my 2 cents to this as it is still un answered. 
Go to the location where you have installed Eclipse. 
You should find a configuration folder. 
Just search for all ".fileTableLock" files in that directory and its sub directories and delete those files.

You should be able to restart your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution with myeclipse and word¿ks, specifically I tried this:

1. backup on a zip all your files from this folder
2. delete the files 
   the folder is
   \MyEclipse 2017 CI\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi.manager

restart myeclipse